# how to fix inverted 'ok' text in flatbutton?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm beginner in flutter. trying to design login page. when user clicks on 'ok' button then 'ok' button gets invisible and 'approved' named button gets visible using some animation. problem is that 'ok' displayed in inverted form as shown in pic. how dI correct this issue?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Animation class',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => stateClass();
}

class stateClass extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;
  Animation<double> sizeAnimation;
  int currentState = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 60).animate(animationController)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    sizeAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Animation login'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  height: 100,
                  //color: Colors.black,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Image.asset('assets/fluttericon.png'),
                  )),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'enter your email id',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'enter your password',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                // color: Colors.teal,
                //   height: 0,
                child: Center(
                    child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: sizeAnimation.value - 1,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: animationController.forward,
                    color: Colors.redAccent[200],
                    child: Text(
                      'ok',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
              ),
              Container(
                //color: Colors.teal,
                height: 80,
                child: Center(
                    child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: sizeAnimation.value,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: animationController.reverse,
                    color: Colors.redAccent[200],
                    child: Text(
                      'approved',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Text container

```
Container(
  // color: Colors.teal,
  // height: 0,
  child: Center(
    child: Transform.scale(
      scale: sizeAnimation.value-1 ,
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: animationController.forward,
        color: Colors.redAccent[200],
        child: Text(
          'ok',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
   )),
 ),
```

When I change sizeAnimation.value-1 to sizeAnimation. then 'ok' word is in erect form. but ok button is not invisible.

[Screenshot preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSZyt.jpg)

Comment: Your explanations are confusing. Please try to be concise and to the point of your specific issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for what you are trying to do is to use Fade and Rotate transitions with separate controllers for each Text widget. Here's an example of that:

```
class ButtonTextFadeRotation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonTextFadeRotationState createState() => _ButtonTextFadeRotationState();
}

class _ButtonTextFadeRotationState extends State<ButtonTextFadeRotation> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _okAnimationController;
  AnimationController _approvedAnimationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _okAnimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      value: 1
    );

    _approvedAnimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      value: 0
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ClipRect(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _okAnimationController.reverse();
            _approvedAnimationController.forward();
          },
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FadeTransition(
                opacity: _okAnimationController,
                child: RotationTransition(
                  turns: _okAnimationController,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text('Ok'),
                ),
              ),
              FadeTransition(
                opacity: _approvedAnimationController,
                child: RotationTransition(
                  turns: _approvedAnimationController,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text('Approved'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```